# Tkinter geometry method to only set width or height

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

The following will set a `tkinter` window width *and* height.

```
root.geometry("500x500")
```

Is it possible to only set width *or* height?

Where can I find a full list of `geometry` method variations, for setting only select parameters?

I would like to be able to set select parameters, of the window size and/or position, and let the rest be under tkinter dynamic control.

Comment: No you cannot set only width or height using `geometry()`, but you can use `config(width=...)`.

Answer (score 4):

When looking at the [tcl/tk documentation](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/wm.htm#M42), we can see that we do not have to provide a full `"widthxheight±x±y"` string to the `.geometry()` method:

- with only `"widthxheight"`, the size of the window will be changed but not its position on the screen.
- with only `"±x±y"`, the position will be changed but not the size.

However, it is not possible to set separately the width and height of the window with this method. Nevertheless, you can retrieve the dimension you don't want to change and use it in `.geometry()` with something like

```
def set_height(window, height):
    window.geometry("{}x{}".format(window.winfo_width(), height))

def set_width(window, width):
    window.geometry("{}x{}".format(width, window.winfo_height()))
```

Note: Using `root.config(width/height=...)` only works for me if the window has never been resized with the mouse or using `.geometry()`

Comment: This is a good answer. But it has a side effect that the other dimension becomes static, and no longer under tkinter dynamic control.

Comment: @mcu Yes, I know but tkinter also loses dynamic control when the user manually resizes the window, so I think it is better in general not to assume that tkinter has it. However you can force tkinter to get dynamic control back with `geometry("")` and then use Tkinter Lover's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use `root.config(width=100)` or `root.config(height=100)`

Comment: This only works for me if the window is empty *and* has not been resized by user or by `geometry` method. As soon as I pack a widget into it, dynamic sizing takes over. `root.pack_propagate(0)` does not help.

Answer (score 1):

If you define a frame within your window you can set width and height of this frame separately like this:

```
myframe = tk.Frame(width=200)
```

This may create the appearance you wish to achieve.

An example program demonstrates how to use this trick:

```
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()
window.title('Frame Demo')

frame = tk.Frame(width=300)
frame_2 = tk.Frame()

label = tk.Label(master=frame_2, text="Frame_2")
label.pack()

frame.pack()
frame_2.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

The frame by the name `frame` is used only to widen the window and is invisible. No GUI elements should be placed in it. Its only function is to give the main window the needed size of 300, in this example. `frame_2` is the canvas, so to say, for the GUI elements.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).